# How to multiprocess the job using different directory to run the process

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I want to run a certain process in different directories at the same point of time with using multiprocessing and divide the threads equally among the process.

I have written some function to pool the job, but I am not having clarity about how should I start.

```
import os
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool

os.system("source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC")

def run_gromacs_simulation():
  pdb2gmx()
  add_ions()


if __name__=='__main__':
   with Pool(4) as p:

    def pdb2gmx():
        pdb2gmx="gmx pdb2gmx -f *.pdb -o conf.gro -ignh <<END \n"
        pdb2gmx+="1\n"
        pdb2gmx+="1\n"
        os.system(pdb2gmx)
        os.system("gmx editconf -f conf.gro -o pbc.gro -c -d 0.8")
        os.system("gmx solvate -cp pbc.gro -cs spc216.gro -o solvated.gro -p topol.top")
        os.system("gmx grompp -f ions.mdp -c solvated.gro -p topol.top -o ions.tpr")
```

I just want to run the os.system() in different directories at the same point of time with multiprocessing and dividing the threads.

Comment: Instead of using `os.system()`, use the [`subprocess module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Which alows you to more carefully control what you're executing, and also to set `cwd` as a parameter (that is, set what the process uses as its working directory)

Comment: actually, I can do that, but I am not looking for that.